# How do not show SNS notification on Android Device if app is currently in the foreground running?

Tags: android, amazon-sns

How do not show SNS notification on Android Device if app is currently in the foreground running?

My device is being registered with Amazon SNS by a server. And the server code will fire notifications.

What do I need to do in my android app to not show the notification if the app is currently up and running in the foreground?

Comment: please let us know if you are using the android example code provided by amazon web services documentation for sns!